# New Okta Developer Server - How to enable Interaction Code? ("Embedded widget sign-in support" not available in Account Settings)

Tags: javascript, okta

I have created a new Okta account with the purpose of setting up a new organization and integrate with a new React application. I would like to create a custom signup/login page. From the documentation I have followed, it seems that I need to [enable the "Interaction Code" grant type](https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/implement-grant-type/interactioncode/main/#enable-interaction-code-grant-on-your-authorization-server).

However, I do not have the checkbox for enabling this grant type on my identity provider. I followed [this documentation](https://help.okta.com/oie/en-us/Content/Topics/Settings/embedded-sign-in-support.htm) from Okta on enabling this feature.

When I navigate to the Settings > Account page, I do not have an "Embedded widget sign-in support" panel to enable "Interaction Code".

I have been attempting to integrate my React application with this Okta Identity Provider using the "@okta/okta-auth-js" library.

However, when I attempt to using the `idx.register()` method of the auth client, I encounter this error: "The requested feature (Interaction Code flow) isn't enabled in this environment. Ensure that you have Okta Identity Engine enabled and the Interaction Code flow enabled for this application and authorization server.".

This is what has led me to trying to enable the "Interactive Code" grant type.

Answer (score 0):

This is only available if your Okta Instance is using the Okta Identity Engine instead of the Classic Engine. You'll need to wait for the Self-Service Upgrade to rollout, or reach out to Okta support/your account manager to start the upgrade process.

https://developer.okta.com/docs/concepts/interaction-code/